# Transformation of a uniform random variable with an exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the question for context:

A financial analyst tracking the price of a particular stock uses the uniform distribution between 1 and 2 as the model for the distribution of stock price P one year from now. A second analyst analyzing the same stock price uses the uniform distribution on the interval from 10 to 100 as the model for distribution of $10^Q$ one year from now (Q is the stock price one year from now). Find $M_p-M_Q$, the difference in the median stock price one year from now as estimated by the first and second analyst.

The solution, for analysis Q, or the 2nd analyst:  (I understand completely every single part up until the under-brace with the 2 stars )

$P[Q\leq M_Q]=P[10^Q\leq 10 ^{M_Q}]=\underbrace{\frac{10^{M_Q}-10}{100-10}}_{\star\star}$

for the part in question, what I DO understand is that this is the general CDF formula for continuous U, $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$

WhatI don't understand, is what the "a" and "b" parts revert to being just the limits of the original uniform random variable. Is it because the solution is implying that what we are in fact looking at is $\frac{x-a^Q}{b^Q-a^Q}$ with Q=1?

If I am correct about this, is there some more generalizable understanding of transformations of uniform random variables also being uniform random variables?